# sum clause method calculating the total with alias name?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[K_FS_GetFeedDivisionReport] 
@orderno varchar(50)
AS
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;
select OT.OrderNo,FT.Feedtype,ModeofPack='Plastic',BG.Bagtype,OD.Numofbags,   
(OD.numofbags*BG.Bagtype) as TotalQty,sum(TotalQty) as Total from  
K_FS_OrderconfirmDetails OD
inner join K_FS_bagtype BG on OD.bagtype=BG.sno
inner join k_FPS_FeedType FT  on FT.sno=OD.feedtype
inner join K_FS_OrderDetails OT on OT.sno = OD.orderno where OD.orderno = @orderno
group by  OT.OrderNo,FT.Feedtype,BG.Bagtype,OD.Numofbags
END
```

Here I calculate `TotalQty`,I want to calculate sum of `TotalQty` but `TotalQty` is a alias name
Is it possible?other wise how can i solve it..please help me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, you can do it like this :

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[K_FS_GetFeedDivisionReport] 
@orderno varchar(50)
AS
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;
select OT.OrderNo,FT.Feedtype,ModeofPack='Plastic',BG.Bagtype,OD.Numofbags,   
(OD.numofbags*BG.Bagtype) as TotalQty,sum(OD.numofbags*BG.Bagtype) as Total from  
K_FS_OrderconfirmDetails OD
inner join K_FS_bagtype BG on OD.bagtype=BG.sno
inner join k_FPS_FeedType FT  on FT.sno=OD.feedtype
inner join K_FS_OrderDetails OT on OT.sno = OD.orderno where OD.orderno = @orderno
group by  OT.OrderNo,FT.Feedtype,BG.Bagtype,OD.Numofbags,OD.numofbags*BG.Bagtype
END
```

If you need totalQty for each row you should use a subQuery:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[K_FS_GetFeedDivisionReport] 
    @orderno varchar(50)
    AS
    BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    select OT.OrderNo,FT.Feedtype,ModeofPack='Plastic',BG.Bagtype,OD.Numofbags,   
    (OD.numofbags*BG.Bagtype) as TotalQty,
    Total = (Select Sum (OD.numofbags*BG.Bagtype) from  K_FS_OrderconfirmDetails OD
    inner join K_FS_bagtype BG on OD.bagtype=BG.sno
    inner join k_FPS_FeedType FT  on FT.sno=OD.feedtype
    inner join K_FS_OrderDetails OT on OT.sno = OD.orderno where OD.orderno = @orderno)

 from  
    K_FS_OrderconfirmDetails OD
    inner join K_FS_bagtype BG on OD.bagtype=BG.sno
    inner join k_FPS_FeedType FT  on FT.sno=OD.feedtype
    inner join K_FS_OrderDetails OT on OT.sno = OD.orderno where OD.orderno = @orderno
    group by  OT.OrderNo,FT.Feedtype,BG.Bagtype,OD.Numofbags,OD.numofbags*BG.Bagtype
    END
```

Comment: what do you mean? you want Query String, or the result? because result is the same `sum(OD.numofbags*BG.Bagtype) = sum(TotalQty)`

Comment: I edited my response and gave you another solution, may it works for your purpose.

Comment: yes,but i want to calculate the sum of "TotalQty" column ..i mean all rows of Totalqty

Comment: Oh, I Got it now you need a sub query for that , Like `TotalQty = (select SUM(OD.numofbags*BG.Bagtype) 
        from  
    K_FS_OrderconfirmDetails OD
    inner join K_FS_bagtype BG on OD.bagtype=BG.sno
    inner join k_FPS_FeedType FT  on FT.sno=OD.feedtype
    inner join K_FS_OrderDetails OT on OT.sno = OD.orderno where OD.orderno = @orderno)`

Comment: you are right but I kept them in the case they may change the record number in main query.As all the joins are inner join.Technically they shouldn't but just in case I don't know the structure.

Comment: You're welcome, as @MilenPavlov said based on your tables if you know that removing `FT` and `OT` in the subquery  `from clause` won't change anything it's better to remove them.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this using sub query.
Modify your select statement this way:

```
  select OT.OrderNo,FT.Feedtype,ModeofPack='Plastic',BG.Bagtype,OD.Numofbags,   
       (OD.numofbags*BG.Bagtype) as TotalQty,
       (select SUM(OD.numofbags*BG.Bagtype) 
        from K_FS_OrderconfirmDetails OD inner join
        K_FS_bagtype BG on OD.bagtype=BG.sno ) 
        as Total
  from K_FS_OrderconfirmDetails OD
        inner join K_FS_bagtype BG on OD.bagtype=BG.sno
        inner join k_FPS_FeedType FT  on FT.sno=OD.feedtype
        inner join K_FS_OrderDetails OT on OT.sno = OD.orderno where OD.orderno = @orderno
  group by  OT.OrderNo,FT.Feedtype,BG.Bagtype,OD.Numofbags
```

This will calculate total for everything in the last column.

Answer (score 0):

Can you not do: 
     SUM(OD.numofbags*BG.Bagtype) as TotalQty,sum(TotalQty) as Total

Comment: I see you are already grouping by OD.numofbags*BG.Bagtype so the sum won't have nay effect. Do you want to sum (OD.numofbags*BG.Bagtype) for all rows in the set?

Comment: You could assign the sum for OD.numofbags*BG.Bagtype for all rows by removing the grouping the grouping to a variable and return the variable with the alias in the final select in your stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

If you want those totals you need to remove the group by on numofbags etc, the moment you start grouping on the values your calculating with your nolonger making a complete sum.